# TTTableView and Search issue with Three20 library.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, three20

I am working with the `SearchTestController` demo as part of `TTCatalog` in [three20](http://three20.info) and have found that if another `TTTableViewController` is called from the search screen (via URLs with `TTNavigator`) on the first view, the top row of the second tableview is concealed by the navigation bar.  This only occurs when calling from the first View when the search screen is up (and the keyboard displayed, etc).

I have been able to 'address' this by adding:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,-40) animated:YES];
```

Into the `viewWillAppear` on the second controller but this doesn't really solve the problem because when the tableview bounces it returns to a position where the first row is concealed.

Any advice/suggestions would be much appreciated here.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can adjust the self.tableView.frame every time the search appears or hides. But I'm not sure why your header is appearing period in the search controller. The header bar should go away - can you post a screenshot of what you see?